# Holomorphic function definition at point and on closed set.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

I was reading Complex Analysis By E Stein and Shakarchi.
In that Following 2 defination I had occured [image]

[image]

As $z_0$ single point which is also closed in $\mathbb C$
So by definition of Holomorphic on Closed set, It says that around some open containing $z_0$ is holomorphic (differentiable).
But I am not able to prove this form definition of Limit.
How to prove this ? or my observation is wrong.
ANy Help will be appreciated

Comment: I think I understand now.  The original definition of holomorphic at the point $z_0$ seems to be in conflict with the definition of holomorphic on the singleton set $\{z_0\}.$  Is that it?  I learned complex variables, out of Alfors, where there was was no concept of holomorphic at a single point.  The function has to be differentiable on an open connected set.  Anyway, you won't encounter any functions differentiable only at isolated points as you move forward.  Good catch, but it's not going to be a stumbling block.

Comment: But $f(z)=|z|^2$ is only differentible at 0.But not in any nbhd

Comment: Why isn't this differentiable in any neighbourhood?

Comment: I'm not saying that no such functions exist, just that they are not the objects of study in complex variables.

Comment: @NDewolf There are no non-constant, real-valued analytic functions.

Comment: Yes of course. Stupid mistake of mine, i didn't take into account the fact that $f(z)$ was real-valued.

Comment: From what i know, holomorphicity is used only for functions that are complex-differentiable in an (open) neighbourhood.

Answer (score 4):

**Note** first that these are not the standard definitions!

This set of definitions seems like a very bad idea, giving non-standard definitions for such basic concepts. It also seems like a bad idea regardless of whether it's standard, because the definition of "holomorphic at $z_0$" and "holomorphic on $\{z_0\}$" are not the same - that seems like they're trying to be confusing.

That last point resolves the confusion about the function $f(z)=|z|^2$: by these definitions it is holomorphic at $0$ but it is not holomorphic on $\{0\}$. No contradiction, but hideous terminology.

Here are the three corresponding *standard* definitions:

$f$ is *differentiable at* $z$ if $f$ is defined near $z$ and $f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0}((f(z+h)-f(z))/h$ exists.

If $\Omega$ is open and $f:\Omega\to\Bbb  C$ then $f$ is *holomorphic in* $\Omega$ if $f$ is differentiable at $z$ for  every $z\in\Omega$.

(In particular we only speak of "holomorphic" *in* an open set.)

If $E$ is any set and $f:E\to\Bbb C$ then $f$ is *analytic on* $E$ if $f$ can be extended to a function holomorphic in some open set containing $E$.

I can't imagine why S&S changed the standard terminology. The standard definitions seem much less likely to lead to the sort of confusion you express in your question.